# image upload using via sync adapter

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-image, android-bitmap, android-syncadapter

After an image is selected and the onActivityResult is called, I create a thumbnail to update the original activity view. I also scale the image down and store it in a temporary folder from where it is then picked up by the sync adapter to be uploaded to the server.

To store the scaled-down version of the image I use AsyncTask. The problem is that the file storing routine is slow and can take up to 10 seconds.

```
File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
fos.close;
```

While image storing is in process, there is a high chance that users can click to upload the image before the storing routine is done. So, I either have to come up with a way to keep retrying the action until the image file is ready, or make storing routine part of the UI thread which will still make users wait, but this time for the thumbnail to appear.

Has anyone done something similar? Are there patterns for handling similar situations etc?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this in one of my application, You can do the saving of the image in a async task and, have an loading spinner (On action bar or anywhere you like) until the file is been saved,

And also by the time async task runs and finished up the saving of the file, You can enable the upload button.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I have right now - I show the spinner on the thumbnail image. This way even though the thumbnail image is shown immediately, the spinner still hints users that there is something to wait for.